# How to change header title size in Jekyll "Time Machine" theme?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I would like to change the much too big font size of my header title in the "Time Machine" theme but am struggling to find the right (S)CSS section.

The four scss files I have integrated into my GitHub repository are (as recommended):

```
jekyll-theme-time-machine.scss
normalize.scss
rouge-base16-dark.scss
time-machine.scss
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any setting for title font size when searching for "title" or "header". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In the Time Machine Jekyll theme source code, you can find the title styling in `time-machine/_sass/jekyll-theme-time-machine.scss`.

Here is a direct link to the styling for the title: https://github.com/pages-themes/time-machine/blob/3058bb3387eddf03eccad3ff2397bc82766f52e8/_sass/jekyll-theme-time-machine.scss#L28-L35

Answer (score 0):

The header size is not defined in the `scss` files but in the `default.html` file in _layouts:

```
<header>
      <h1 class="title">{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</h1>
</header>
```

This means that changing the headline from `<h1>` to a `<h2>` headline makes the font smaller.

Comment: I would recommend you move this answer into your original question as it is additional details to your question rather than an answer to your question.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make clear why this fixed my issue for now. It is, however, not the best answer, I agree.